# Third party Google Cast devices

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

Is Google Cast open to third party receiver devices (DIAL 1st-screen devices), or will ChromeCast remain the only option? 
Can we expect SmartTV makers to natively support the cast protocol, so that a ChromeCast device will not be needed?

As a developer, what do I have to implement in order to be a Google Cast device?

Comment: There is an app that emulates Google Cast https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.maui.cheapcast

Comment: @Mustafa I know about those emulators (there's one for iOS called rPlay and another for Python called leapcast). However they are all based on reverse engineering of the protocol. What I want is an official guide for hardware/software builders.